# Look up field not showing results - Lightning Component via Lightninh Out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

I built a form using [Lightning Universal Lookup Component - Managed Package](https://www.synebo.io/blog/Lightning_Universal_Lookup_Component_Version_2_10).

I'm using it in two different fields, here is the first field where it's working perfectly.

[image: Working Lookup field]

This is the markup for that field.

```
<l_lookup:Lookup
        aura:id="campus"
        objectType="Account"
        isRequired="true"
        label="Campus"
        pluralLabel="Campus"
        selectedRecordId="{!v.newStudent.Launchpad__Campus__c}"
        queryCondition="RecordType.Name = 'Community College'"
/>
```

---

And this is the Lookup field giving me issues.

[image: Weird behavior lookupfield]

This is the markup for that field.

```
<l_lookup:Lookup
    aura:id="faculty"
    objectType="Contact"
    isRequired="true"
    label="Faculty"
    pluralLabel="Faculty Contact"
    selectedRecordId="{!v.newStudent.Faculty__c}"
    queryCondition="RecordType.Name = 'Partners'"
/>
```

I just realized something right now doing some testing (Removed the queryCondition attribute), and it's that for the field that is giving me issues it's not showing the records of RecordType Partner, but I changed the record type of an existing record to Partner and now gets shown just that one and not the others, like this.

[image: Weirdest thing ever]

**Worth to mention:**

- This happened the first time I exposed the component in Lightning Out, it fixed itself the day after.
- I also test it inside the Community and works perfectly.
- CORS is set up like this:

[image: CORS]

I find this extremely weird.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've been away from this post, I was able to solve it that day, the issue was happening because of a Permission on the object in Sharing Settings.

So this was a very isolated issue and if you face a similar problem in some moment this is the way to solve it.

Thanks for your time.